# por qué overflow ROMPE la propiedad {position:fixed;} ??, exíste solución?

Tags: css

éste código trabaja 100% bien al abrirse con cualquier teléfono y cualquier browser PC:

```
<?php
echo <<<HTML
<html><head><style type="text/css">
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
html,body{
background:teal;
color:#0f0400;
height:100%;
}
.tc{text-align:center;}

#menu_1_with_icon{
background:tan;
color:#000;
display:inline;
margin-top:-2px;
position:fixed;
}
#menu_1_with_icon:before{
border:1px solid #000;
content:'☰';
}
</style><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head><body><div id="cosmos">
<div id="menu_1_with_icon"></div>
HTML;
echo str_repeat('<p class="tc">jump!</p>', 98);
echo '</div></body></html>';
```

sin embargo si agregas la línea:

```
echo '<table border="1"><tr><td>https://deliciasnaturales.com/stackoverflow/rwd/template_rwd_menu.php</td></tr></table>';
```

el "botón" del menú **☰** PIERDE la propiedad `fixed`.
( es decír al agregar CUALQUIER elemento que genere OVERFLOW )

1. el error **únicamente se aprecia** al cargar desde teléfonos
2. cuál es el error de mi código CSS?
3. **NO** PRETENDO solucionar el "overflow"
4. por qué la propiedad **fixed** se pierde?
5. tiene solución sin utilizar ni librerias ni JQUERY ni BOOTSTRAP?

pueden abrir el código con un teléfono (SIN la tabla y CON la tabla) desde aquí:

https://deliciasnaturales.com/stackoverflow/rwd/

( la tabla solo prodúce un OVERFLOW, es irrelevante; pueden utilizar CUALQUIER ELEMENTO que genere OVERFLOW y se dañará el "fixed" discúlpen que lo díga de nuevo: increiblemente únicamente sucede con ANDROID )